# Optimizing $\prod x_i^{ax_i+b}$ subject to $\sum x_i = C$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I would like to obtain a bound for the maximum value of the function
$$
F(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \prod_{j=1}^n x_j^{ax_j+b}
$$
in the simplex $S_n$
$$
S_n = \{(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x_j \geq 0 \text{ and }\sum_{j=1}^n x_j = C\}.
$$
Here $a,b,C>0$ are some positive constants.

To optimize $F$ it suffices to optimize $\log F$,
$$
\log F = \sum_{j=1}^n (ax_j+b) \log(x_j),
$$
and then the Lagrange multiplier condition for $\log F$ to have a critical point is that there exists a constant $\lambda$ such that
$$
\partial_{x_i} (\log F) = \lambda
$$
for all $1\leq i\leq n$.
This leads to the equation
$$
\partial_{x_i} (\log F) = 
a\log(x_i) + \frac{ax_i+b}{x_i} = \lambda.
$$
If the function $a\log(x_i) + \frac{ax_i+b}{x_i}$ were injective, one could conclude that
the only critical point is at the value $(C/n,C/n,\dots,C/n)$, and since the function vanishes at the boundary of $S_n$ (and is positive in the interior) it must be the case that this is the maximum.

However this function is not injective, and this is not the only critical point.  In fact, in the simple case $n=2$ and $a=b=1$ I found (with numerical help) the example
$(x_1,x_2) = (0.318, 6.305)$, which satisfies
$$
x_1^{x_1+1} x_2^{x_2+1} > m^{2m+2}
$$
where $m = (x_1+x_2)/2$.

Given this example it seems difficult to characterize the location of the maxima of $F(x)$, and I am curious whether there still might be a relatively simple bound for
the value of
$$
\sup_{(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in S_n} F(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n).
$$
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Remember that Lagrange multipliers lead to extremum values (maxima and/or minima). Your problem is simple for the minimum not for the maximum but at least you have a lower bound of it.

Comment: I have something potentially interesting for the maximum. Look at my edit.

Comment: Let me know if the question is still of interest to you. I found quite many things which make the problem very interesting.

Comment: This actually is still of interest!  I can get by in my application with very crude bounds but it would still be nice to have a better understanding.

Comment: I think that I should add some more elements in the very next days.

Comment: Have a look at my second answer and come back to me. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\partial_{x_i} (\log F) = a\log(x_i) + \frac{ax_i+b}{x_i} - \lambda=0$$ gives
all $x_i=\frac C n$  but this corresponds to a minimum value of $F$.

Using your example $a=b=1$, $n=2$, $C=\frac{6623}{1000}$, I also find $x_1=0.317849$, $x_2=6.30515$, $\log(F_{max})=11.9410$ while $\log(F_{min})=10.3252$.

**Edit**

I have a serious problem. From a lot of numerical studies, varying $(n,a,b,C)$, it *appears* (no proof at all) that, at the maximum, all $x_i$'s but one are identical. The other one is close to $C$.

For example, using $n=4$, $a=2$, $b=3$, $C=123$, I obtained
$$x_1=122.279 \qquad x_2=x_3=x_4=0.240 \qquad\qquad F_{max}=1174.95$$

*Admit* that this is true. Let
$$x_1=x_2=\cdots=x_{n-1}=t \qquad \text{and} \qquad x_n=C-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_i=C-(n-1)t$$ This makes
$$\log(F)=(n-1)  (a t+b)\log (t)+ (a u+b)\log (u)\qquad \text{with} \qquad u=C-(n-1)t$$ So, we need to solve for $t$ the derivative
which can be easily solved by Newton method starting with $t_0=\epsilon$. Since starting close to $t=0$, cross multiply to remove the denominator. This makes the equation to solve
$$G(t)=b (c-n t)+a t u \log \left(\frac{t}{u}\right)=0\qquad \text{with} \qquad u=C-(n-1)t$$

For the above example, this would give
$$4 t-2 t(t-41)  (\log (123-3t)-\log (t))-123=0$$ and Newton iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & t_n \\
 0 & 0.001000 \\
 1 & 0.139207 \\
 2 & 0.234742 \\
 3 & 0.240184 \\
 4 & 0.240197
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Let $h(x) = (ax+b)\log x$. Notice $h''(x) = \frac{ax-b}{x^2}$ which is +ve for $x > \frac{b}{a}$ and -ve when $x < \frac{b}{a}$. $h(x)$ is convex on $(\frac{b} {a},\infty)$ and concave on $\log(x)(ax+b)$. In order to maximize $\sum_i h(x_i)$ subject to $\sum_i x_i = C$, the convexity on $(\frac{b}{a},\infty)$ tell us there is a most one $x_i \in (\frac{b}{a},\infty)$ and concavity on $(0,\frac{b}{a})$ tell us all $x_i \in (0,\frac{b}{a})$ needs to share same value. This will explain what you observe at maximum (aside from the case all $x_i$ is same), all but one $x_i$ is identical.

Comment: @achillehui. Thanks for this nice explanation. Do you have any idea for a $t_0\neq \epsilon$ (arbitraty ? Cheers :-)

Comment: No idea about the general case. I have tried a little bit last night but nothing useful comes out.

Comment: @achillehui. There are many interesting features in this problem. If you have time to waste, take the specific case given in the question $(a=b=1,c=6.623)$ and maximize the function for $n=2,3,4,\cdots$. The point where the function is maximum is "almost" a constant. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

*I prefer to add another answer to throw in a few ideas, remarks and preliminary results.*

**First remark**

At least to me, the key problem is to first find the value of $x$ which makes the function maximum. So, we can already get rid of parameter $a$ writing

$$F= \prod_{j=1}^n x_j^{ax_j+b}=\Bigg[\prod_{j=1}^n x_j^{x_j+\beta} \Bigg]^a\quad \text{with} \quad \beta=\frac b a$$
$$G=\prod_{j=1}^n x_j^{x_j+\beta}\implies \log(G)=\sum_{j=1}^n (x_j+\beta)\log(x_j)$$
$$\frac d{dx}\log(G)=\sum_{j=1}^n \Big[1+\frac \beta {x_j} +\log(x_j) \Big]$$ As said in the previous answer and justified by @achillehui in comments, at the maximum, all $x_j$'s but one are identical. So, as before, let
$x_1=x_2=\cdots=x_{n-1}=t$ to make
$$H=\frac d{dx}\log(G)=(n-1) \left(1+\frac{\beta }{t}+\log (t)\right)+\left(1+\frac{\beta }{x_n}+\log (x_n)\right)\tag 1$$ with $x_n=C-(n-1)t$

Solving $(1)$ for $t$  using Newton method should not present any problem. To save iterations, what would be required is a "good" estimate of the starting point (which would be a function of $n$, $\beta$ and $C$).

**Second remark**

Numerically, for given values of  $\beta$ and $C$, the solution of $(1)$ *does not seem* to be   very  sensitive to the value of $n$.

For the two  examples worked in the question $\left(t_n^{(1)}\right)$ and the first answer $\left(t_n^{(2)}\right)$ some results

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & t_n^{(1)} & t_n^{(2)}\\
 2 &  0.317849 &  0.240020 \\
 3 &  0.324726 &  0.240108 \\
 4 &  0.332738 &  0.240197 \\
 5 &  0.342311 &  0.240286 \\
 6 &  0.354172 &  0.240376
\end{array}
\right)$$

Many other numerical tests *seem* to show that $n=2$ provide a lower bound of the solution.

**Third remark**

The plot of $H$ is not pleasant because of the infinite branch when $t\to 0^+$ but the product $(t\,H)$ is much more interesting. Using a Taylor expansion of it around $t=0$ gives

$$t \,H=\beta  C (n-1)-(n-1) t (-C \log (t)+C \log (C)+\beta  n)+O\left(t^2\right)$$
Using this expansion gives, as an *estimate*,
$$t_0=-\frac{\beta }{W_{-1}\left(-\frac{n\beta  }{C}e^{-\frac{\beta }{C}}\right)}\tag 2$$ where $W_{-1}(.)$ is the second branch of Lambert function.

Applied to the worked cases, this would give $t_0^{(1)}=0.292136$ and $t_0^{(2)}=0.238273$; this does not seem too bad.

Comment: Excellent work!   Thanks so much!